# Change colour of line numbers in listings package

Tags: color, listings

While the documentation of the famous `listings` package explains to modify many things, I wonder how to change the colour of the line numbers when I use something like

```
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add it to the numberstyle

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny\color{red}, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
a
b
c
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, LaTeX can be so easy :-) Thank you.